# Laravel5.8 I cannot store data to my sql server

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, store

I am setting up user profile page, but I cannot insert data into `mysql` server.

I cannot figure it out and solve this issue.

I have `index.blade.php` in my profile folder, and from index page, going to `create.blade.php` .

> When I enter the submit button, my page redirects to `index.blade.php`,
>   but in `mysql` server, nothing is recorded.

**web.php**

```
Route::prefix('user')->group(function(){
    Route::resource('profile', 'UserController');
});
```

**create.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{route('profile.store')}}" method="POST">@csrf

                    <ul class="information">
                        <li>Name :<br>
                            <input type="text" class="name" name="name">
                        </li><br>
                        <li>Gender :<br>
                            <div class="gender">
                                <select name="gender" id="" name="gender">
                                    <option class="option" value="" selected="selected">Select Gender</option>
                                    <option value="male" >Male</option> 
                                    <option value="female" class="selected">Female</option> 
                                    <option value="any">Any</option> 
                                </select>       
                            </div>
                        </li>   
                        <li>Country :<br>
                            <div class="country">
                                <select name="country" id="" name="country">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option> 
                                    <option value="United States" class="selected">United States</option> 
                                    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>      
                                </select>
                            </div>    
                        </li><br>
                        <li>Birthday :<br>
                            <input type="text" class="birthday" id="bod" name="bod">
                        </li><br>
                        <li>User Description :<br>
                            <textarea name="description" id="" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea></li>
                    </ul>
                    <button type="submit" class="saveBtn">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('profile.index');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('profile.create');
    }

public function store(Request $request) {

        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        Profile::where('user_id',$user_id)->update([
            'name'=>request('name'),
            'gender'=>request('gender'),
            'country'=>request('country'),
            'bod'=>request('bod'),
            'description'=>request('description')
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('profile.index');
    }
```

Profile.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','name', 'gender', 'country', 'bod', 'description'
    ];
}
```

Comment: what will be the result when you `dd($request('name'));` runs inside `store` function? are you getting the correct value?

Comment: it is not clear if you are trying to store new record or update an old one. if it is new, I guess you are supposed to be using the save() instead of update.

Comment: @GayanS.Muthukumarana 'Function name must be a string' appeared.

Comment: @fmsthird I want to insert a first record.

Comment: I have put an answer. try that

Comment: then better to use save()

Comment: do you have a previous row in profile with `user_id` that you are trying to update??

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Where is all that code going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to update an existing record:

```
$user_id = auth()->user()->id;

$update = Profile::where('user_id',$user_id)->update([
                'name'=>$request->name,
                'gender'=>$request->gender,
                'country'=>$request->country,
                'bod'=>$request->bod,
                'description'=>$request->description
            ]);

    if($update){
        return redirect()->route('profile.index');
    }else{
        //do something if fails
    }
```

But if you need a add a new profile then:

```
$create= Profile::create([
                    'user_id'=>auth()->user()->id,
                    'name'=>$request->name,
                    'gender'=>$request->gender,
                    'country'=>$request->country,
                    'bod'=>$request->bod,
                    'description'=>$request->description
                ]);

        if($create){
            return redirect()->route('profile.index');
        }else{
            //do something if fails
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work, I still have a same error when I try dd($request('name'));

Comment: what is the result when you `dd($request->name);` ?

Comment: I got a name I put 'John Doe' !

Comment: ok then you just need to add this in your `Profile` Model : `protected $fillable = ["name", "gender", "country" ,"bod", "description"];`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assuming that you are trying to post new record:

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $profile = new Profile;

    $profile->name = $request->input('name');
    $profile->gender = $request->input('gender');
    $profile->country = $request->input('country');
    $profile->bod = $request->input('bod');
    $profile->description = $request->input('description');

    $profile->save();

    return redirect()->route('profile.index');
}
```

Comment: I could insert data, but I need user_id because user has one profile.

Comment: can you include the Profile model in your post

Comment: you can add `$profile->user_id = auth()->user()->id;`

Comment: Thank you ! I could make it ! But how can I store an edited data ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code only update the `Profile` model if it exists in the first place. If you do not know if a record exists, you may want to try the [updateOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods) method. It will update existing record or, if no such record, it will create a new one:

```php
public function store(Request $request) {

    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

    Profile::updateOrCreate(
        ['user_id' => $user_id], // search requirements
        [
            // fields to update or create record with
            'name' => request('name'),
            'gender' => request('gender'),
            'country' => request('country'),
            'bod' => request('bod'),
            'description' => request('description')
        ]
    );

    return redirect()->route('profile.index');
}
```

Comment: I got an error ['user_id' => $user_id], here $user_id is not defined.

Comment: Did you assigned `$user_id` by running this: `$user_id = auth()->user()->id;`?

Comment: This is just to replace the `Profile::where` statement, not the whole method body.

Comment: @YoheiUmezu: Updated my answer to show the full code of the modified `store` method.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Profile` model make `'name', 'gender','country''bod','description'` make these fields **fillable**.

Answer (score 0):

in your user model make a relation of userProfile like this

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['what ever you want to fill in user model'];

    public function userProfile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

then you can update you relational data like this in your controller

```
$user = ['user_id'=>auth()->user()->id];

$order->location()->updateOrCreate($user, $arrayOfData);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your Model use this,

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'gender', 'country'];
```

or if you can use this,

```
protected $guarded=[];
```